# Display list of categories filtered by date?

Tags: categories, plugin-list-category-post

I have a sidebar on our intranet which lists, hierarchically, posts by category.

Such as:

```
-- HR
---Events
----Picnic
```

However, this list has gotten long, and some categories are no longer even used.  I would like to only category links where there are posts less than a year old.

Right now, I am using the default Categories Widget in the sidebar, but I can use a different widget or hand-code it.

How would I best approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this question is correctly tagged since you mentioned you're using the Categories Widget. The tag is for the [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) plugin.

Using the plugin, the first possible thing that comes to my mind is using the few available date parameters:

> **monthnum** and **year** - List posts from a certain year or month. You can use these together or independently. Example: `[catlist
>   year=2015]` will list posts from the year 2015. `[catlist monthnum=8]`
>   will list posts published in August of every year. `[catlist year=2012
>   month=12]` will list posts from December 2012.

This is not available on the widget (yet), but you could add it as a shortcode in your template file:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[catlist id=3]"); ?>
```

Comment: I didn't realize I tagged it the plugin, sorry. I'll try that solution, though, thanks.